# UL code on front page display is pushing down the last LI element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I started a new job this week and one of my duties will be fixing/updating the website.

Our front page has six floated elements with mouse behaviors wrapped in a UL.  In Firefox and IE, it appears just fine.

In Chrome, the last li element is lower than the others by about 20 or so pixels (I tried removing the style that was on the "last" element which changed the top margin (-18), but it didn't change anything).

The site is at rlba.com.  If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jquery and etc)

Comment: Thank you for the help ... I will edit the post later today.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question...

Set `#flashContainer2 ul`, line 274 in your styles.css file, to have a width of 942px and a display of block.  This will correct the behavior you are experiencing.

But please listen to j08691 and alireza safian in your comments and fix your question so that other people can learn from this.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- and I will build a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for your ul to be display:inline, especially if you have a defined height, so remove your display attribute and let it be the default (display:block;).

Then remove the default browser padding on the ul to have it be flush with the left side of your site's content container.

```css
#flashContainer2 ul {
    width: 940px;
    height: 420px;
    /* display: inline; - remove this */
    padding: 0; /* add this */
}
```

And lastly, your li tags in the ul are 155px wide with padding-right of 2px (so the li is effectively 157px) but the ul is 940px wide. 157x6 = 942px. So you could either remove the width on "#flashContainer2 ul" so it grows to the container and becomes 942px wide, or remove the 2px padding from the last element so all of the li's fit in the ul.

```
#flashContainer2 .lastInList {
    padding-right: 0; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @Drenmi thanks, I'm new. Edited with an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was exactly what I needed.